# i have an Excel of URL , One URL is redirecting to another how would i test it through Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have an excel of URL's in which there are 4 columns , OLD t_id , Old URL and New t_id and new URL , I have to test the URL redirection through selenium Web driver.
please suggest any Idea

Answer (score 1):

Use `@DataProvider` to rotate through your excel data, read old_url from excel and navigate to it using `driver.get()`, Use `driver.getCurrentUrl()` to get the new redirected url string. Compare it with string from excel new_url column.